# BeautifulSoup doesn't find match

Tags: python-3.x, url, beautifulsoup, extract

I'm trying to extract a [URL](http://forum.xda-developers.com/attachment.php?attachmentid=3827565&stc=1&d=1469815165) from [this](http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=1916098) page using BeautifulSoup by searching for the URL anchor text. I've tried several different approaches with BeautifulSoup, including a different html parser, but none of these have been successful.

Code:

```
import requests
import re
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

url = "http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=1916098"

response = requests.get(url)

soup = BeautifulSoup(response.content, "lxml")

print(soup.find('a', text=re.compile('FULL OPTIMIZED')))
```

What am I doing wrong? Alternative ideas are welcome.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are multiple [strings](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#string) in the anchor so it gets set to None, you have a few options, one just look for the *string/text* and get the parent:

```
print(soup.find(text="FULL OPTIMIZED").parent)
```

Two, check the text/string after finding the anchors:

```
anchors = soup.select("a[href^=http://forum.xda-developers.com]")
print(next(a for a in anchors if "FULL OPTIMIZED" in a.text))
```

Of use the *Version* string in font tag and again get the parent:

```
print(soup.find('font', text=re.compile('Version')).parent)
```

All three will give you:

```
<a href="http://forum.xda-developers.com/attachment.php?attachmentid=3827565&amp;stc=1&amp;d=1469815165" target="_blank">FULL OPTIMIZED<font size="4"> Version</font></a>
```